# Password length and complexity

Tags: linux, centos, password, authentication

I am using CentOS and I want to set the minimum password length, minimum password expiry , maximum password expiry and password complexity  in my system.

I have looked over some tutorials to change the system-auth file, but it didnt work.

Hoping to get some answers here.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Which tutorials? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: Added few lines in the system-auth file  but nothinghappens.

Comment: It still accepts any password you give them when i do "passwd"

Comment: What lines did you add? What tests did you do to check that “nothinghappens”?

Answer (score 2):

Some of those are set by the system administrator with the `passwd` command.

> **-n** This  will  set  the  minimum password lifetime, in days, if the user's account supports password lifetimes.  Available  to  root only.
>
> **-x** This  will  set  the  maximum password lifetime, in days, ...

Other are managed through the PAM module cracklib. The `pam_cracklib` man page should document what features are supported on your system. You can set those in either /etc/pam.d/system-auth global configuration file and/or the passwd specific file /etc/pam.d/passwd e.g.

```
# /etc/pam.d/passwd
... 
password  required pam_cracklib.so difok=3 minlen=15 dcredit= 2 ocredit=2
```

Comment: I tried doing that in the system-auth file still no changes were observed when i actually changed the password

Comment: Could you amend your question with the contents of the relevant pam.d configuration files?