# Disable password complexity check (PAM)

Tags: linux, password, pam, passwd

I installed a Linux based system with a blank password. I wanted to change password to something simple, but using `passwd` and setting the password to something like a single symbol gave an error of “password being a palindrome”.

How to disable password complexity checks?

Comment: I like this question and your answer, and do not feel they are duplicates as the question is more generic and the answer is detailed.  However, I feel I should link two other relevant posts in case someone is looking to bypass without completely disabling:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324073/how-can-i-bypass-fedoras-password-complexity-requirments
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139290/password-length-and-complexity

Comment: @Jesse_b Thank you! I did not know about bypass before.

Answer (score 6):

I found out my system (as most modern Linux) use `PAM` (Pluggable Authentication Modules) and `pam_cracklib` module within it. `pam_cracklib` enforces minimum length of 6 symbols regardless of parameters, so solution is to turn it off.

One link I've read discussed editing `password-ac` and `system-ac` files in `/etc/pam.d`, the contents of both files were same and no explanation was given of their respective roles.

Upon study of `PAM` docs ([The Linux-PAM System Administrators' Guide | linux-pam.org](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/Linux-PAM_SAG.html)), I learned `PAM` configs for LINUX services are in that `/etc/pam.d` directory in separate files. I saw `passwd` file and it in found only `system-ac` file mentioned (added by `substack` keyword), so on my system I needed to edit only `system-ac`.

Making `pam_cracklib` `optional` made no difference (I guess that's because `pam_cracklib` did not pass entered and rejected pasword to next module in stack - `pam_unix`) and commenting line with `pam_cracklib` lead to errors during `passwd` run. I noted that next line with ordinary `pam_unix` had option `use_authtok` (docs: enforce the module to set the new password to the one provided by a previously stacked module). After I deleted that option and commented line with `pam_cracklib` I now able to set short passwords with `passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of PAM modules that can do password strength checking. There's at least [`pam_cracklib`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib) that comes with many distributions, and [`pam_passwdqc`](http://www.openwall.com/passwdqc/) from Openwall ([packaged in e.g. Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libpam-passwdqc)). Also, some versions of the usual file-based authentication module `pam_unix` have options that are related to password strength, like `minlen` for minimum password length, and `obscure` which makes some tests to compare the new password to the old one. (The name comes from 'the "obscure" checks in the original shadow package'.)

You'll need to check your PAM config for any such modules, and either disable or uninstall them. Look for lines starting with the keyword `password` for the modules related to password changes. The exact structure of the the configuration may depend on the distribution.

Also, if you have users stored on LDAP or other such network based system, it's not impossible for the server itself to have requirements for the user password. In this case, the PAM configuration on the client would not be relevant. E.g. OpenLDAP has a [password policy overlay module](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Password%20Policies).

Comment: In my current Gentoo/Linux box I change my password with the standard `passwd` command. I have found the relevant PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d/passwd`, which `include system-auth`, that is `/etc/pam.d/system-auth`. In there `password required pam_passwdqc.so config=/etc/security/passwdqc.conf` points me to the final configuration file in this trip. `man passwdqc.conf` explains that I can let root user free by editing `enforce=users` (instead of the existing `everyone`) in there.

Answer (score 1):

in `/etc/pam.d/common-password` change this line:

```
password requisite pam_pwquality.so retry=3
```

to

```
password requisite pam_pwquality.so dictcheck=0 retry=3
```

means set dictcheck=0, it will ignore the dictionary check

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt autoremove libpam-sss
```

problem solved

Comment: Hi, welcome to U&L. I think this answer is too short and a bit flippant, as there are other implications to just removing the libpam-sss package that are not explained - I can think of `/etc/nssswitch.conf` entries from the top of my head. Would you be able to explain these?